# I need a software for speech recognition from multiple people and transcription in Arabic

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-synthesis

I need a software that is able to recognize several people (possibly 5-10) speaking at the same time and transcribe the audio, also for it to be able to do this for arabic language.

IBM Watson is similar to what i'm talking about but they don't have arabic available as a language https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/text-to-speech/